# How can I copy an entire JavaScript object to update a MongoDB/Mongoose document, that contains nested arrays and subdocuments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema that looks like this (minimalized/ adapted for question):

```js
const grandchild = new mongoose.Schema({
    bar: String
}


const child = new mongoose.Schema({
  foo: Number,
  children: [grandchild]
});

const parent = new mongoose.Schema({
  baz: String,
  children: [child]
}

const Parent = mongoose.model("Parent", parent);
```

And I am required to update an existing `Parent` (as in essentially **replace/ copy the entire object)** given a JavaScript object from an express `put` request body, which reflects the mongoose schema exactly:

```
{
  baz: "Baz",
  children: [
    {
      foo: 50,
      children: [
        {
           bar: "abc"
        },        
        {
           bar: "xyz"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
       foo: 20
    },
  ]
}
```

I am required to update a document, and send back the updated version.

I have tried doing this (Given I know the ID of a parent document):

```js
app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
   const updated = Parent.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, req.body, {new: true});

   // (I do convert to something sendable via express, but omitted here as irrelevant 
   res.json(updated)
}
```

This seems to correctly copy the `parent` and `child` documents, but the grandchild objects in the subdoc array are not copied over, and I get a result that is missing the children object of each `child` subdocument:

```
{
  baz: "Baz",
  children: [
    {
      foo: 50,
    },
    {
       foo: 20
    },
  ]
}
```

So how can I basically deep copy the entire javascript object to update the mongoose document?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I had a spelling mistake in the schema model, and so it wasn't updating it correctly.

It works now.